# knockoutjs bindings issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I'm having issues with my knockoutjs implementation. Seems to be working fine on Chrome and Safari IE and FF have thrown a hissy fit.

The message which I encounter is as follows:

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: TypeError: 'AccountName' is
>   undefined; Bindings value: value: AccountName

The issue is happening within a script tag which serves as a knockout template:

```
<div id="newAccountDialog" class="dialog" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width: 350, title: 'Exchange Account'}, template: { name: 'dialogFormTemplate', data: CurrentAccount }, openDialog: IsNew"></div>

<script id="dialogFormTemplate" type="text/html">
    <form id="dialogForm">
        <h1>Exchange Account Manager</h1>
        <p>Add new or edit an existing exchange account settings.</p>
        <label for="AccountName">
            Account
        </label>
        <input id="AccountName" name="AccountName" type="text" data-bind="value: AccountName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <div class="buttonsContainer floatRight">
            <button id="Save" data-bind="click: $root.SaveAccount, dialogcmd: { id: 'newAccountDialog', cmd: 'close'}, jqButton: { icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-disk' } }">Save & Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

I assume some sort of early binding is being triggered on the template

> data : CurrentAccount

where an undefined / null is being passed into CurrentAccount. I have seen this issue outside of script tags, but only if the observable is not defined or null.

My viewmodel looks as following:

```
    var AccountModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Accounts = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.CurrentAccount = ko.observable(null);
    self.IsNew = ko.observable(false);

    self.LoadAccounts = function () {
        $account.invoke("GetAccounts", {}, function (data) {
            var mapped = $.map(data, function (item) {
                var account = new Account(item);
                var innerMapped = $.map(item.Mailboxes, function (mailbox) {
                    return new Mailbox(mailbox);
                });
                account.Mailboxes(innerMapped);
                return account;
            });
            self.Accounts(mapped);
        });
    }

    self.EditAccount = function (data) {
        self.CurrentAccount(data);
        self.IsNew(true);
    }

    self.SaveAccount = function () {
        if (self.CurrentAccount().Id() <= 0) {
            $account.invoke('AddAccount', ko.toJS(self.CurrentAccount()), function (data) {
                self.Accounts.push(new Account(data));
                self.CurrentAccount(new Account(data));
                self.IsNew(true);
            });
        } else {
            $account.invoke('UpdateAccount', ko.toJS(self.CurrentAccount()), function (data) {
                //self.CurrentAccount(new Account(data));
            });
        }
    }

    self.CreateAccount = function () {
        self.IsNew(true);
        var account = { Id: 0, AccountName: '', IsNTLM: -1, Email: '', Password: '', Domain: 'mydomain', ExchangeVersion: 1, Mailboxes: [] };
        self.CurrentAccount(new Account(account));
    }
};
```

My dialog bindingHandler is defined as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).dialog('destroy');
        });
        $(element).dialog(options);
    }
};
```

I have ommited the Account object, as it is possibly not required in this context.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "early" binding in Knockout. Everything is bound when you call `ko.applyBindings`. But certain bindings can stop or delay binding of their descendant elements. `template` is one of those when you use the `if` or `ifnot` options. In your case, you can use the `if` option like this:

```
template: { name: 'dialogFormTemplate', data: CurrentAccount, 'if': CurrentAccount }
```

Note: The quotes around `if` are required in some older browsers.

Comment: Michael, there is a reason why your surname is Best. Enough said. Thank you. the 'if' fixed the issue.